# Why we need patterns like 2PC or SAGA to perform sequential transactions between microservices?

Tags: architecture, microservices, saga

The problem I am having is Why we even need a pattern like SAGA (Asynchronous) or 2PC(Synchronous) to perform transactional inter-service communications between microservices ?  .Because we can achieve that with a naming server. I mean let's think if a microservice goes down when it's in a middle of a transactional call so can't the naming server route that request to a different instance of the microservice required ? So then there won't be any unavailability among microservices .

Ex: A and B are microservices all those microservices are registered in a naming server like Eureka , A need B to complete the transaction by performing a inter-service communication. But unexpectedly B went down .So then naming server can route A's request to a different instance of B no .So where is that unavailability. So now why we need those patterns ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a matter of high availability but of data consistency, it is the same reason why we need transactions in a relational database. They are not needed only because the database connection could fail during a transaction, but because we want that the whole operation either succeed or fail.
And this could include problems like constraints that are not met during inserts or updates.. etc.

And this problem could be applied to distributed transactions too. It could happen that you want that two operations in different microservices either succeed or fail. And if one of these operations fails, because the instances of that microservice are down, but also because an insert/update in the database fails due to any other reason, you want to revert the whole operation even the other call has succeeded and the changes have been committed.

And because of this, you need tools like saga pattern to implement compensating actions to revert the changes when this kind of things happen.

Comment: What kind of issues does SAGA or 2PC solves rather than solving providing high availability.

Comment: As I said before, they provide data consistency more than high availability. They ensure that all the operations are made or none of them. It is the same as transactions in a traditional RDBMS, they do not provide high availability but data consistency when multiple changes are made

Comment: @JAgrente can't it achieve with the traditional approach .I mean I already mentioned we can have a naming server to provide high availability by automatically routing to the available instances. So can't we rollback the transactions based on http responses. Ex: In a failure of microservice B it will give response status as 500 to A.

Comment: @JAgrenete I guess according to your suggestion following the SAGA will make it easier, rather than following the traditional approach as I suggested . I am I correct ?

Comment: But you can't rollback a transaction that has already been committed in service A because there is an error on service B, the only way you can do to revert the commit in service A is to define compensating actions or other mechanisms that saga pattern provides

Comment: @JAgrente I can simple delete the changes which are made to microservice A's database if the status is 500 .

Comment: this kind of actions are the ones that provides saga pattern but in more general way. For example, it is possible that the changes made in A are not an insert but an update, and it is possible that the distributed transaction involves 5 different services and if the third connection fails it implies revert the changes made by the second.. etc

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.